# pandas.Series.str.contains() is not finding a string which exists in the Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm trying to match a bunch of names from a list to the names in one of the columns of a Pandas DataFrame. A small part of the DataFrame is shown below:

[image: sample-values-pandas-df]

The values in the columns "Object ID" had some whitespace which I stripped using the line:

```
df["Object ID"] = df["Object ID"].str.strip()
```

I am searching the column "Object ID" using the following line:

```
df[df["Object ID"].str.contains('EM* LkHA 115') == True]
```

The above line is returning an empty dataframe eventhough 'EM* LkHA 115' exists in the dataframe as shown below:

[image: value-exists-in-df]

Any idea what I could be doing wrong ? I would be happy to provide any further information if it would be of help.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the '*' char.

```
df[df["Object ID"].str.contains('EM\* LkHA 115')]
```

also you don't need the == True

As @MustafaAydın says in the comment below you can use the regex lib to do this dynamically.

```
import re

df[df["Object ID"].str.contains(re.escape('EM* LkHA 115'))]
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks! I did not realize that. Any idea how would I do dynamically? As in, the object names are stored in a list and I'm iterating over that list.

Comment: do you need the ids to contain `*` ?
if not you culd remove the char from the object id in the dataframe:
`df["Object ID"] = df["Object ID"].str.replace("*","")`

Comment: @kkin `import re` and then `...str.contains(re.escape(your_string))` to escape dynamically.

Comment: @MustafaAydın omg thank you i did not know re had that method, that makes life easyer